# All CURL functions returns null in php

Tags: php, curl

php5-curl is installed but `curl_exec()` returns `null`, `curl_errno()` returns `0`, `curl_error()` returns `null`, `curl_getinfo()` looks like `curl_exec()` never fired.

Sample of code

```
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0';
    $curlOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>str_replace(' ', '%20', $url),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$agent,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>"GET",    
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER=>true,    
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>5,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>600,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS=>20,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false
    );

    curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $curlOptions);
    $result = curl_exec($this->curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($this->curl);
    $this->log->ToLog('HTTP error on downloading ' .$url.' ; error = ' . curl_errno($this->curl) . " => ". curl_error($this->curl) . ' ; status = '. json_encode($status) , 'info');
```

In log I can see

> HTTP error on downloading `https://cdn-a.verkkokauppa.com/576/images/83/2_175586-1250x758.jpeg` ; error = 0 => ; status = {"url":"https://cdn-a.verkkokauppa.com/576/images/83/2_175586-1250x758.jpeg","content_type":null,"http_code":0,"header_size":0,"request_size":0,"filetime":0,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":0,"namelookup_time":0,"connect_time":0,"pretransfer_time":0,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":-1,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":0,"redirect_time":0,"redirect_url":"","primary_ip":"","certinfo":[],"primary_port":0,"local_ip":"","local_port":0}

But `file_get_contents()` works fine in this case. What happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `echo curl_error($this->curl);` ? Instead of `str_replace()` you should use `urlencode()`

Comment: @DanFromGermany He has that in his question. It's empty.

Comment: if you have an access into your terminal , try to execute your curl using the terminal and check what the output will be

Comment: Just tried it on my local machine and it worked fine.

Comment: I try it on my desktop and it work but on server it doesn't. Also I test console version of curl and wget - file downloaded fine. But PHP version still doesn't work